# MSSQL DISTINCT again

Tags: sql-server

This query work perfectly on MySQL, but I should rewrite to work with MSSQL and this doesn't work

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 [UF].[id], [UF].[created], [Company].[name]
FROM [user_functions] AS [UF] 
LEFT JOIN [companies] AS [Company] ON ([Company].[code] = [UF].[company_code]) 
WHERE [UF].[user_id] = 8923 AND [UF].[state] != 500 
ORDER BY [UF].[created] DESC
```

This query return duplicated rows, even i set `DISTINCT`.

But, when remove `[Company].[name]` from `SELECT` it's return correctly.
I would like using many fields from `[Company]` and `[UF]` tables.

Comment: Removed MySQL tag because MySQL does not support TOP syntax... next time please tag the correct tag(s)

Comment: You should provide example tables with data and expected output

Comment: It must be returning slightly different values for `[Company].[name]`

Comment: Provide example of what MySQL does that MSSQL does not

Answer (score 0):

You can try row_number and get the first rownum as below:

```
select * from 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 [UF].[id], [UF].[created], [Company].[name],
    RowNum = row_number() over(partition by [Company].[name] order by [UF].[ID])
    FROM [user_functions] AS [UF] 
    LEFT JOIN [companies] AS [Company] ON ([Company].[code] = [UF].[company_code]) 
    WHERE [UF].[user_id] = 8923 AND [UF].[state] != 500 
) a where RowNum = 1
order by a.Created Desc
```